# How to get all field names of javascript class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Example code:

```js
class Demo{
    field1 = 1;
    field2 = 2;
    
    method1(){
        return this.field1 + this.field2;
    }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Demo.prototype));
```

I want to get all field and method names before instantiate it。

The result :

[image]

expect :

```
['field1','field2','method1']
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, class fields and methods are not enumerable by default, so you cannot use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` or `Object.keys()` to get the list of fields and methods defined in a class.

However, you can use the `Reflect.ownKeys()` method to get all the keys (including symbols) of an object, which will include all the fields and methods defined in the class.
Here's an example:

```
    class Demo {
  field1 = 1;
  field2 = 2;
  method1() {
    return this.field1 + this.field2;
  }
}

const instance = new Demo();
const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(instance);
const protoKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance));
const allKeys = [...keys, ...protoKeys];
console.log(allKeys); // ["field1", "field2","constructor", "method1"]
```

if you want to remove the constructor you can achieve this using

```
const keys = allKeys.filter(key => key !== "constructor");
console.log(keys); // ["field1", "field2", "method1"]
```

Comment: sorry,  the result is：  ['constructor', 'method1']

Comment: @user16685541 sorry my mistake, can you please check again

Comment: It works,  but I hava to get feild  names before instantiating. Maybe  It is impossible, because  class fieds will be parsed to   `function Demo(){
   this.field1 = 1;
   this.field2 =2 ;
}`, wich not exists in A.protoype